# How to display really tall ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, knitr

For example, while trying to display a facetted plot with one hundred rows:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
tmp_d <- data.frame(group = rep(1:100, each = 5), 
                    x = rep(1:5, times = 100),
                    y = runif(1:500))
## looks like
#   group x         y
# 1     1 1 0.5929813
# 2     1 2 0.7264811
# 3     1 3 0.3704220
# 4     1 4 0.5149238
# 5     1 5 0.3776632
# 6     2 1 0.4183373
# ...

ggplot(tmp_d, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ group, ncol = 1)
```

I get a mess in the plotting window in Rstudio which I cannot zoom into or scroll:

[image]

Inconvenient work-arounds involve `ggsave` or `knitr`:

#### Using `ggsave`:

```
ggsave('tmp_20170104_long_ggplot.png', p, height = 100, limitsize = F)
```

#### Using `knitr`:

Embed the plot in a `knitr` code chunk with a large arbitrary value for `fig.height`:

````
---
title: "Test plot of tall ggplot2"

output:
    html_document
---

```{r, fig.height = 100}
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
tmp_d <- data.frame(group = rep(1:100, each = 5), 
                    x = rep(1:5, times = 100),
                    y = runif(1:500))

ggplot(tmp_d, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ group, ncol = 1)
```
````

#### Two questions:

1. How do I easily display such plots?
2. How do I determine what the height value has to be for each of the work-arounds?

Comment: A plot with 100 panels seems ... ill designed.

Comment: @Roland why? I just want to print it so I can look at each individually.

Comment: Do you intend to print it on a house wall? Produce separate plots.

Comment: Why would producing separate plots have any advantage, apart from being easier to produce from the default plot options?

Comment: Because then you could switch between them without scrolling, arrange them however you like and can actually print them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- try `dev.new(width=3, height=10, noRStudioGD = TRUE)`. If your plot is too tall for the screen, you can draw it on a pdf file an use the pdf viewer to scroll,

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
tmp_d <- data.frame(group = rep(1:100, each = 5), 
                    x = rep(1:5, times = 100),
                    y = runif(1:500))

p <- ggplot(tmp_d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ group, ncol = 1)

nc <- length(unique(ggplot_build(p)[["data"]][[1]][["PANEL"]]))

ggsave("tall.pdf", p, width=7, height = nc * 7 + 2, limitsize = FALSE)
```

[image]

2- if you have N rows of panels and each panel should be H inches tall, something like N x H plus some room for axes etc. should work well.

Comment: thanks, seems promising, although the supplied arguments caused my R session to crash :(

Comment: hmm, try a more explicit device, e.g. `x11()`, or `quartz()` etc. Rstudio may also try to interfere (maybe the cause of the crash?), so try from an independent vanilla R session as well.

Comment: when you try plotting my graph using your arguments, what do you get? I have tried in a vanilla R session and the size is still not right. (Also, resizing the window from a vanilla R session causes R Gui to crash).

Comment: I don't get any crashes, but my screen is not tall enough to display 100 vertical panels. Can't you use facet_wrap instead, or split the plot over multiple pages?

Comment: Ah, so there is no scrol/zoom functionality for viewing plots in R? By split the plot, do you mean make multiple plots?

Comment: if you want scrolling, one option is to plot on a pdf, and let the pdf viewer handle the scrolling. I don't know of interactive devices that have scrolling capability. Yes, I mean separate plots.